# How to download source code of package_name into specified directory ？

Tags: command-line, apt, source

The following command downloads the source code of pure-ftp into the current directory.

```
apt-get source pure-ftp
```

How to download it into specified directory?

I want to download the source code of pure-ftp into /tmp directory. We can't write it this way:

```
apt-get source pure-ftp -output /tmp
```

How to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of anyway to specify where it downloads the source to, but I know you could run it as one line to force it to download to a folder of your choice.

- If you run your command this way:

  ```
  cd /tmp && apt-get source pure-ftpd
  ```

  It will change the present working directory to `/tmp` then download the source code into the `/tmp` folder for you.

  Or, you could do the line this way with the ability to return to the directory you were just in:

  ```
  cd /tmp && apt-get source pure-ftpd && cd $OLDPWD
  ```
- The best is the add this line as a permanent function to `~/.bashrc`

  ```
  apt-get-source(){ cd $2 && apt-get source $1 && cd $OLDPWD; }
  ```

  Then use it as:

  ```
  apt-get-source pure-ftpd /tmp
  ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `apt-src`? The `man` page says:

```
trusty (1) apt-src.1p.gz
Provided by: apt-src_0.25.1-0.2_all bug

NAME
       apt-src - manage debian source package trees

SYNOPSIS
       apt-src [options] command

       apt-src [options] install|remove pkg1 [pkg2 ...]

       apt-src location pkg

DESCRIPTION
       apt-src is a command line interface for downloading, installing,
       upgrading, and tracking debian source packages. It can be run as a
       normal user, or as root.
```

Works for me!